# Reading hidden value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have this hidden value in a form. That I can see value in the browser using firebug.

```
   <div class="idF">
                <input type="hidden" id="Id1" name="Id" value="{=Id}" />
   </div>
```

When I try to read this value in jquery using

```
        var test=$("#Id1").val();
        alert(test)
```

I get alert message "undefined". Please let me know what I am doing worng. 
Thanks

Comment: You are probably executing your JS before the DOM is loaded. [This code is fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/yUZzu/)

Comment: Thanks that was one of the problem too. Its working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you get ID when DOM is ready?

Works fine for me if I use `ready` handler

See [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zAx3y/)

Comment: Thanks for the hint I changed the function the way you had it and also I was using JS before DOM was loaded. Thanks

Comment: @J.Davidson np, don't forget to accept answer if it was helpful ;)